# How to get the fragment instance from the FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

I set the content view in the FragmentActivity, and the activity will create the fragment instance for me according to the class name specified in the layout file. But how can I get that fragment instance?

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle extra) {
        super.onCreate(extra);
        setContentView(R.layout.page_fragment);
    }
}
```

layout/page_fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/pageview"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:name="org.xi.android.PageFragment" />
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can use use `findFragmentById` in `FragmentManager`.

Since you are using the Support library (you are extending FragmentActivity) you can use:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pageview)
```

If you are not using the support library (so you are on Honeycomb+ and you don't want to use the support library):

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.pageview)
```

Please consider that using the support library is recommended even on Honeycomb+.

Comment: Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833912/refresh-fragment-ui-from-fragmentactivity

Comment: this won't work if you have multiple instances of the frame fragment on the backstack.

Answer (score 40):

To get the fragment instance in a class that extends FragmentActivity:

```
MyclassFragment instanceFragment=
    (MyclassFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.idFragment);
```

To get the fragment instance in a class that extends Fragment:

```
MyclassFragment instanceFragment =  
    (MyclassFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.idFragment);
```

Comment: 'tis the right answer. The other (validated) answer doesn't work in the case of fragments using support library v4, as used in the question (FragmentActivity only present in support library)