# How to refresh a fragment after language change is applied in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app uses fragments extensively. It is supposed to support 3 languages - English, Arabic and Kurdish. The home screen consists of a navigation drawer which holds a menu of options one of them is languages which opens a language selector dialog. The language selector has 3 buttons - English, Kurdish and Arabic clicking on a button changes the language like so -

```
private void setLocale(String code){
        Configuration config=new Configuration();
        Locale locale = null;
        locale=new Locale(code);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.locale=locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                  context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        dismiss();

    }
```

I have added the following code to onConfigurationChange -

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int count=fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();

        BackStackEntry latestEntry=(BackStackEntry) fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(count-1);
        String str=latestEntry.getName();
        Fragment fragment=fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(str);
        if(fragment==null){
            return;
        }
        FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragTransaction.detach(fragment);
        fragTransaction.attach(fragment);
        fragTransaction.commit();
```

And I have added the following to android manifest -

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

but nothing seems to be happening. I also tried - [Is it possible to refresh the view of a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889175/is-it-possible-to-refresh-the-view-of-a-fragment) without much luck. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the second proposition of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12771054/4576054

Answer (score 0):

seems to me that if you listen to configuration changes you should also override the [`onConfigurationChanged`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)) method in either the Fragment or the hosting activity and then update the UI using the new Locale as needed instead of detaching and re-attaching you just popegate a method into the children of the activity and re-populate all the fields as needed

Comment: refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9733622/1056359)