# Access View created in Fragment from main activity

Tags: android

I created a view in a fragment

```
public static class GraphSectionFragment extends Fragment 
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        GraphView view = new GraphView(getActivity());
        view.setGraphType(GraphView.GraphType.Oscillator);          
        return view;
    }
}
```

Now I need to access my GraphView object from main activity. How do I?
I tried it this way, but it doesn't work.

```
GraphSectionFragment fr = (GraphSectionFragment) m_SectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(0);
View v = fr.getView();
GraphView graph = (GraphView)v;
graph.setData(0, m_DeviceThread.getRangeDataI());
```

m_SectionsPagerAdapter is an object of a class inherited from FragmentPagerAdapter. Fragment.getView returns the view of some strange class, not GraphView.

Answer (score 3):

You will get your answer at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8545206/968526).
you can access fragment from activity by either way depending on your implementation.

To get the fragment instance in a class that extends FragmentActivity:

```
MyclassFragment instanceFragment= (MyclassFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.idFragment);
```

OR

To get the fragment instance in a class that extends Fragment:

```
MyclassFragment instanceFragment =
(MyclassFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.idFragment);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can retrive your activity by doing the following:

```
(MyActivity)getActivity();
```

So if your `GraphView` is set to a public variable in your class you can do:

```
GraphView graph = ((MyActivity)getActivity()).myGraph;
```

or set an accessor function:

```
GraphView graph = ((MyActivity)getActivity()).getGraphView();
```