# Get Fragment by Id in Activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        class="com.xamarin.recipes.filepicker.FileListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/FileListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

After that I am trying to get access to FileListFragment in Activity:

```
var fileListFragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.FileListFragment);
```

but I get "Unknown identifier: fileListFragment" in Watches for fileListFragment

**Update.**

Activity code:

```
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.OS;

namespace com.xamarin.recipes.filepicker
{
    [Android.App.Activity(Label = "Choose file", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class FilePickerActivity : FragmentActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ChooseAudio);

            var fileListFragment = (FileListFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.FileListFragment);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Go to this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532462/how-to-get-the-fragment-instance-from-the-fragmentactivity?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532462/how-to-get-the-fragment-instance-from-the-fragmentactivity?rq=1)

Comment: Why you are using `var`in java? Javascript is another language :) Try like: `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById`if you use support library.

Comment: @Hardy This is Xamarin... not Javascript!

Comment: Can you try this : `FileListFragment fragment = (FileListFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.FileListFragment);`

Comment: @ManishMulimani, tried it - doesn't help

Comment: Where are you trying to use `fileListFragment`? The scope of `fileListFragment` ends at the end of `onCreate` method. Try to manually debug or put some log statements to check whether `fileListFragment` is valid.

Comment: Hi @Idsa do you see my updated answer? Does it help you? You should really try the last solution with `as FileListFragment;`, I think this is the missing part which occured the issue. Let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Use This:

```
 getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.FileListFragment))
```

Comment: The question is about Xamarin

Answer (score 2):

I'm not currently using Xamarin, however I undelete my answer because I think I'm near to the solution and this can help you. I found several tutorials or GitHub projects using Xamarin. These searches don't give me the right solution, but I think they give me the clue for your issue. Try this code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
// using Fragment = Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment;

namespace com.xamarin.recipes.filepicker
{
    [Activity(Label = "Choose file", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class FilePickerActivity : FragmentActivity
    {
        // use Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment below
        private FileListFragment mFileListFragment; 

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ChooseAudio);

            mFileListFragment = (FileListFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.fileListFragment);
            // Avoid any confusion: change its id in your layout by "fileListFragment"
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the `var` which seems undefined with `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` by using the fragment class `FileListFragment` as the error says: **Unknown identifier**.

*Note:* be sure that `FileListFragment` extends `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` as follows:

```
public class FileListFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
  ...
}
```

To use a `var`, I guess you need to convert it via `as Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` (a comparator), like this:

```
var fileListFragment = SupportFragmentManager
                       .FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.fileListFragment)
                       as FileListFragment; // you need this line
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I'm not sure but I think it should works.

```
var fileListFragment = SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById<FileListFragment>(Resource.Id.FileListFragment);
```

Comment: There is no typed parameter in FindFragmentById

Comment: @Idsa There is the typed parameter in 'FragmentManager' [documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_2_-_managing_fragments/#1.communicating-with-fragments). I thought that 'SupportFragmentManager' has the same method.

Comment: Seems like documentation is outdated

Answer (score 0):

> Did you tried to get fragment like this

```
 Fragment fileListFragment = SupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.FileListFragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

You already know that the method you've tried won't work, so I am not going to tell say that once again.
Please note that the view of the Fragment is not accessible like this.
Try creating a project with tab navigation using ADT and then look inside the code, it will clarify your concepts.
The wizard will also generate a dummy tab fragment class for you, which will look like

```
public static class FragHomeUI extends Fragment
```

The fragment view will be created and accessible inside following member of the class:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,
                    false);
```

Would say again, create a few sample projects through ADT wizard and observe the code carefully.

Comment: Did you read question and comments before answering? This question is about [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/android)! This is not the right way to create a fragment using this cross-plateform development.

Answer (score 0):

It might Help.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment_byID = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
//OR
Fragment fragment_byTag = fm.findFragmentByTag("fragment_tag");
```

Comment: *Same as the others:* Did you read question and comments before answering? This question is about [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/android)! This is not the right way to use this cross-plateform development.

Comment: It is also possible for the Activity to use the FragmentManager to find Fragments Like : var emailList = FragmentManager.FindFragmentById<EmailListFragment>(Resource.Id.email_list_fragment);

Comment: what exactly you are not able to do?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code in Xamarin.Android 4.12.02001:

`FileListFragment fileListFragment = Android.Runtime.Extensions.JavaCast<FileListFragment>(SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById(Resource.Id.id_file_list_fragment));`