# Get Fragment instance in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface, fragmentmanager, android-framelayout

> I have added Fragment to Activity like

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container,new MyFragment).commit();
```

where `container` is the id of `FrameLayout`

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Now how could i get the instance of **Fragment in Activity** [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532462/how-to-get-the-fragment-instance-from-the-fragmentactivity)

I have to call a method of `Fragment A` after getting result from `Fragment B`.

I have created an interface in Fragment B and implemented it in Activity.Now i have to pass the result to Fragment A. I am unable to get the instance of Fragment A.

> One thing i don't wanna do is to create a private instance of **Fragment A** in **Activity** and call it's method.

Comment: you can make that method static

Comment: Why you want to get Fragment instance? better to make one Interface and override method in Activity and called it from Fragment. This way to got all the data from Fragment A to your Activity

Comment: use this   getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container,new MyFragment).commit();

Comment: Use FragmentTransaction's add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag) method and FragmentManager's findFragmentByTag(String) method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container,new MyFragment(),"MyFragment").commit();
```

for get the fragment

```
MyFragment frag = ((MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyFragment"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Following this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html):

> All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

Thus I would recommend:

1. To define a `interface` in `Fragment B`.
2. Implement the `interface` in `activity`.
3. Then eventually, deliver the message to `Fragment A`.

[Code example and reference.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface)

Comment: Step (3) doesn't follow from steps (1) and (2).